# Glassfish server 3 start failed after password

Tags: passwords, glassfish

I added password to glassfish for admin from localhost:4848
Before adding the password I was able to start the server from netbeans, now I can only start it from console.

In netbeans I get the Glassfish server 3 start failed error and INFO: User [] from host localhost does not have administration access.

I added the following to glassfish-web.xml. I guess I need to add the password too to somewhere in code but I can't find where

```
  <security-role-mapping>
    <role-name>admin</role-name>
    <group-name>asadmin</group-name>
  </security-role-mapping>
```

Comment: which version of NB are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After downloading 7.1, Netbeans started asking password on start up, when I enter the password I can deploy. I could not deploy on previous version. Probably I can start the server from Netbeans now but I got used to starting it from the console.

Answer (score 0):

worked for me: try logging first in browser via http://localhost:4848/management/admin, then deploy on IDE